# How to print data from a webpage? Not the html code of the page.

Tags: java, printing, html

In java I am trying to read a webpage. I want to print only the data of the page. But my code is printing whole html code. It looks weird. I can see the exact data I want it is hiding in the html. How can I get rid of printing the html code?
here is my code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.rxbd.info/Controller/Controller?action=details&drug=zorubicin&group=generic");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream is =con.getInputStream();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null ) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). The [Renderer](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/Renderer.html) class can render the original HTML to text, The TextExtractor class can just extract the text.